# select query to select closest date which is less then or equal to current date in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

this is my table , name is resource_calendar.

[image]

i want to select  **resource_id**  which have effective date less then or equal to  current date and most closest date to current date.

**what will be the right query in postgresql?**

query will

```
select effective date  22 for resource_id=3 and effective date  21 for resource_id=7
```

so result should be

```
  id      resource_id  calendar_id   applied_on               effective_date  version
  19       3            6            2016-12-22 11:13:26.53   2016-12-22      0
  26       7            5            2016-12-22 11:16:26.53   2016-12-21      0
```

Comment: less than?? Isn't it Less than or equal to Current date?

Comment: ya it is less than or equal to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM
(
    SELECT id, resource_id, calendar_id, applied_on, effective_date, version,
           MIN(ABS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (current_timestamp - effective_date))))
               OVER (PARTITION BY resource_id) AS diff
    FROM resource_calendar
    WHERE EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (current_timestamp - effective_date)) > 0
) t
WHERE ABS(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM (current_timestamp - t.effective_date))) = t.diff
```

This query forms a partition by `resource_id` on the `resource_calendar`.  You can think of this partition as a logically grouping records together which have the same `resource_id`.  For each such group of records, it computes the *smallest* difference between the `effective_date` and the current timestamp, where the `effective_date` be earlier than the current timestamp.

The outer query then identifies those records having this minimum timestamp difference.

Postgres has some [reasonably helpful documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) on using window functions if you feel you need more information.

Comment: Why go through all the hassle of `timestamp` math if you have a `date` column and need to compare dates? This is a very wasteful solution and [Durgpal Singh's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41278038/3304426) is far superior.

Comment: @Patrick Good catch, when I answered for some reason I thought `effective_date` _was_ a timestamp, perhaps the question was edited since then.

Comment: @Patrick Using a window function to solve this problem is completely legitimate, and would be the way to go for most other RDBMS, which don't have Postgres' `DISTINCT ON` capability.

Comment: Legitimate is probably not the right word here. Functional, yes; efficient or straightforward, no. `rank() OVER (PARTITION BY resource_id ORDER BY effective_date)` already looks an awful lot better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this. A simple query

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON(resource_id) *
FROM planner.resource_calendar 
WHERE effective_date <= CURRENT_DATE 
ORDER BY resource_id, effective_date desc;
```

Comment: ya it is very simple query and give same result

Comment: Very elegant solution, but I would use `CURRENT_DATE` instead of `now()`, seeing that we are dealing with dates here.